# GeoLiteCity how to understand format of the IP address

Tags: asp.net, geolocation, ip, ip-address

I just update SCV GeoLiteCity file to my DB.
But i realize that i can't understand the format.

startIpNum,endIpNum,locId
"16828416","16828671","109220"

How can i know that "16828416" is 168.28.41.6 or 168.284.1.6 ??

Can someone explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the IP address 174.36.207.186 this produces the number 2,921,648,058.

Here is pseudo-code for turning an integer back into an IPv4 address:

integer_ip = 2921648058

```
o1 = int ( ipnum / 16777216 ) % 256;
o2 = int ( ipnum / 65536    ) % 256;
o3 = int ( ipnum / 256      ) % 256;
o4 = int ( ipnum            ) % 256;

address = ( o1, o2, o3, o4 ).join('.')
```

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/csv/

Comment: It looks like you are referring to the GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv dataset. The first 2 fields are the start and end of the IP range and are interpreted in the manner that molu2008 posted. The third field is a location ID that is internal to maxmind.